# Can only run .NET project on Visual Studio, but not on the terminal

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, terminal

I'm working on a .NET Core 2.x project for my company and it runs just fine on Visual Studio 2019 but it doesn't run in the terminal.

The folder structure has the services, entities, etc, on the same level as the API folder, like so:

```
root
|-- /API
|-- /services
|-- /entities
```

On Visual Studio, it automatically selects the API folder to be run on debug mode.

When I run `dotnet run` from the root project, it prints it cannot find a project to run.

When I run it from the API folder, it prints

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows Service must first be installed and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.

What can I do to run this project in the terminal, without Visual Studio?

Comment: What kind of project is this? An ASP.NET service or a command line tool?

Comment: It's a REST API built with .NET. I have no previous .NET experience, so I'm not sure if it's an ASP.NET service or just something built with pure .NET.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how that works either, but I think these start with a service, not in the terminal.

Comment: So Visual Studio is automatically creating a service in the background?

Comment: I believe so, but as said, I have newer really worked with web services. I only saw that your project structure doesn't match the structure of a standard desktop app, so I expect that it needs to be run differently.

Comment: I see. I will try searching on how to do that and report back.

Comment: Ok, it turns out it was an if-else in one of the files that started it as a service by default, except on Visual Studio.
Adding a flag to dotnet run makes it possible to run it in the terminal.

Thanks for the help, even though it was an in-house problem.